# Did AskUbuntu go viral with Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: discussion

It seems that new users only seem to be posting 12.04 threads, even though the only version in support is Ubuntu 12.04 SERVER (or even that has expired), also even 15.10 is out, why did users switch backwards or whatever?

Comment: **Ubuntu 12.04 is supported until April 2017, both Desktop and Server version.** People using Ubuntu 12.04 are probably satisfied with this version and see no reason to upgrade.

Comment: Alright, alright.

Comment: Also 12.04 is an LTS. I'm personally happier sticking with an LTS release for stability.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1st off: Ubuntu 12.04.1 and 12.04.5 are still valid releases. April 2017 is the end of life date. I would assume 12.04 was just a very popular release.

But even then ... if you look at the 1st page with the tag [`12.04`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/12.04) 7 out of the 1st 10 might be related to a server installation. Of course it is a bit of guessing. I see these 10 as ...

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/688285/upgrading-kernel-from-3-2-to-3-13-on-ubuntu-12-04-with-preexisting-lxc-container LXC containers. Probably a server.
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/688284/installing-ralink-wireless-5370-drivers-ubuntu-12-04 ARM system. Probably would be better off with 14.04
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/688112/ubuntu-12-04-and-lenovo-e450-wireless-card 14.04 would probably be better.
- [Easiest way to update Apache, MySQL & PHP on VPS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/687946/easiest-way-to-update-apache-mysql-php-on-vps) VPS. Bound to be a server and a hosted server too.
- [Use crontab to restart an Upstart service on schedule?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/687423/use-crontab-to-restart-an-upstart-service-on-schedule) Looks like a server to me (his /home/ has a "local" as user. Seems odd naming for a desktop).
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/687247/getting-errorerror-1045-during-phpmyadmin-installation Phpmyadmin. Bound to be a webserver.
- [How to downgrade/unpatch bash for ubuntu 12.04 LTS to get back to the original vulnerable version of it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/687199/how-to-downgrade-unpatch-bash-for-ubuntu-12-04-lts-to-get-back-to-the-original-v) Impossible to guess. He probably wants to test security. Could be a server.
- [how to fix Error: Port conflict: another instance is already running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/687182/how-to-fix-error-port-conflict-another-instance-is-already-running) Postgres. Database. Might be server.
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/687170/guvcview-video-and-audio-dont-sync-in-12-04 Desktop.
- [Ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04, Which is better?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/687061/ubuntu-12-04-or-14-04-which-is-better) Comparison between 12.04 and 14.04 so going to be desktop. Not relevant for this meta question. Can be closed as "biased","optionated".
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/686854/ubuntu-12-04-syslog-connection-refused-from-freenas-9-3 Server.
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/686627/ubuntu-lts-freezing desktop.